# VS Code Api - How can I create a floating widget INSIDE the editor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have made an extension for VS Code (Using Typescript) and I want to show a small widget near a cursor. Something like a Webview would help but I want it to be inside the editor and right next to the cursor `editor.selection.active`

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have the `HoverProvider` that can handle Markdown text

Comment: No, Can you answer with a psuedo/example code? I will try that out

Comment: search the extension samples for the HoverProvider

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.